# How to create a dynamic list in Perl

Tags: perl, list

I've seen several examples online that show how to use an array with a static size and manipulate it with the information. I'm curious how to create a list in `Perl` in which the list's size can be dynamic and items can be add, e.g. something like `append()`.

As a side note, most of the tutorials I've found on google seem to be a bit dated, if you have a suggestion on where I can learn simple stuff like what I asked in this question, please let me know. Thanks.

Specifically, I'm currently looking to build a list of strings, which I can then later reference the list's size and iterate through the values.

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/perl-arrays

Comment: All lists are dynamic in perl. You can `push`, `pop`, `shift`, and `unshift`. See http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html

Comment: @AKHolland: Actually, no. Lists are very much static in Perl. But arrays are dynamic. Arrays and lists are [not the same thing at all](http://friedo.com/blog/2013/07/arrays-vs-lists-in-perl).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays **are** dynamic in Perl.

```
my @lines = ('line one', 'line two');
push @lines, 'line three';
print $_, "\n" for @lines;
```

Output:

```
line one
line two
line three
```

Answer (score 1):

To find good (and not outdated) tutorials on Perl see [learn.perl.org](http://learn.perl.org/) and [perl-tutorial.org](http://perl-tutorial.org/)